# How to use shell bang operators to refer to a previous command on the same command line

Tags: bash, zsh

Let's suppose I'm stringing together two commands on the same command line, and I don't want to type an argument twice.  How do I do this?

```
chmod u+x /some/obnoxiously/long/path && vim <WHAT_GOES_HERE?>
```

If I were typing this on two lines the solution would be `!$`:

```
chmod u+x /some/obnoxiously/long/path 
vim !$
```

But the `!$` gets the last argument from the the last *line* entered not the last *command* executed.  I want a way to get the last argument of the `chmod` command, on the same line before the `&&`.  I'm sure I'm not the first person to want this.  Is there some way for Bash or Zsh (or any other shell) to do this for me?

TLDR: you can skip everything following.  Everything pertinent to *the question itself* is above.

---

***Why would I want this?*** (I know someone will ask.) Lots of reasons.

Sometimes the first command will take a while to run, and I want to type all the commands I'm thinking about right away so that I can turn my attention to something else while the first command runs.  The period during which I'm waiting is a huge opportunity for something to interrupt my thought process.  Sometimes it's another person in the office or at home, and sometimes it's another thought crossing my mind, and sometimes it's something else on my computer going off and distracting me. A break in mental flow is a break in productivity.  Getting it all down at once avoids this.

Sometimes, even though the first command might be nearly instantaneous (as with `chmod`), I just want to pass the entire set of instructions on my mind over to the shell.  It might *seem* like typing two things separated by `&&` is no different than two things separated by <kbd>return</kbd>, but that would be false.  The process goes something like this:

1. type the command;
2. review the command critically, to make sure there are no errors or omissions;
3. hit <kbd>return</kbd>;
4. let the computer execute the command;
5. repeat with the next command.

By using `&&` I can type both commands before moving to steps 2, 3, and 4.  The mental flow is simply better.  And by using `&&` I know that if the first command fails, the 2nd is not going to be run.

Comment: bash and zsh are completely different shells. Unless you would accept an answer that only covers one, this should be split into two questions. (Even if you *would* accept an answer that only covers one, it should probably still be split, because we'd end up a place with two different, equally-right questions and no way to select a single accepted answer if there was one only covering bash and another only covering zsh).

Comment: ...I'd also consider posting a question about *interactive shell use*, rather than *scripting*, at our sister site [unix.se]. Questions about writing a script are explicitly on-topic here, but history expansion (the interactive family of features you're asking about) is disabled by default in scripts.

Comment: BTW, I'd personally write `s=/some/obnoxiously/long/path; chmod u+x "$s" && vim "$s"`. Same duplication avoidance, but portable to all POSIX-y shells (even ones that don't implement optional interactive extensions), and -- since there's no reliance on history expansion -- leveraging practices you'll be able to reuse in a scripted context.

Comment: In general, you can use `!#` to access the command line so far, using other modifiers to select the portion you want.

Answer (score 4):

What goes there is `$_`:

```
$ echo chmod u+x /some/obnoxiously/long/path && echo vim "$_"
chmod u+x /some/obnoxiously/long/path
vim /some/obnoxiously/long/path
```

Here's `man bash`:

```
   Special Parameters
   _      [...] expands to the last argument to the previous com‐
          mand, after expansion. [...]
```